# Surface homeomorphic to an open disc with two congruent curves homoemorphic to a circle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Inspired by the [Problem 5/1964 of Miklós Schweitzer Competition](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=2&cid=152&year=1964&sid=cd00d152e476b0cf3df6882a1054f84d), my question is as follows;

> Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for a surface homoemorphic to an open disc to have two congruent curves homeomorphic to a circle?

Observation: The answer to the general question (in the given link) is No, by constructing a minimal surface which does not have such curves.

Comment: I don't understand the problem because I don't know what definition of 'congruent' you mean.  Are you assuming that the surface has a (Riemannian) metric on it (and 'congruent' means isometric with corresponding geodesic curvatures) or that it is embedded in $3$-space (and 'congruent' means extrinsically congruent as curves in $3$-space)?

Comment: I'm assuming the former definition. 

Comment: Here is the solution to the MS problem http://books.google.com/books?id=2wwXImJ2HocC&pg=PA249#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Gjergji: Thanks for the reference.  @ehsanmo: In fact, the solution described in the passage Gjergji supplied assumes the *latter* definition of 'congruent', rather than the former.  It is a completely different problem. 

Comment: @Robert Bryan: Could you enlighten me the difference? 

Comment: @ehsanmo: Take a surface $S$ in Euclidean $3$-space that has constant Gauss curvature $-1$. Then any two closed curves on $S$ with sufficiently large constant geodesic curvature $\kappa >> 0$ will close at the same length and will be congruent in the first sense, but because the intrinsic isometry that identifies them will not be an ambient isometry, the two curves won't usually be congruent in the second sense.  OTOH, there is a surface with two closed curves that are ambiently congruent but don't have the same geodesic curvature in $S$, so they are not congruent in the first sense.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: Thank you. I really appreciate it!


Comment: @Robert Bryant: Is there any chance to find a sufficient and necessary conditions in that case?